ServiceStack Blazor Modal Not Opening for Editing Existing Player DTO
I'm working with ServiceStack Blazor and using a standard modal provided by the framework to handle CRUD operations in a Blazor web application. The modal opens as expected when creating new records but does not open for editing existing records.
Here’s the issue:
When I double-click on a player record in the grid to edit it, the URL updates correctly to include ?edit=6 (or another player ID), but the modal does not appear. However, for creating a new player, everything works as expected.
Here is my Player DTO:
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using System;

public class Player : AuditBase
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public PositionPlayer Position { get; set; }
    public string TrainerId { get; set; }
}

public enum PositionPlayer
{
    ATT,
    CC,
    DF,
    GK
}

API Endpoints:
     [Tag("players"), ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Description("Create a new Players")]
   [LocodeCss(Field = "col-span-12 sm:col-span-6", Fieldset = "grid grid-cols-8 gap-2", Form = "border overflow-hidden max-w-screen-lg")]
   [ExplorerCss(Field = "col-span-12 sm:col-span-6", Fieldset = "grid grid-cols-6 gap-8", Form = "border border-indigo-500 overflow-hidden max-w-screen-lg")]
   [Route("/players", "POST")]
   [ValidateHasRole(Roles.Employee)]
   [AutoApply(Behavior.AuditCreate)]
   public class CreatePlayer : ICreateDb<Player>, IReturn<BoolResponse>
   {
       [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Description("Name of Player"), ValidateNotEmpty]
       public required string Name { get; set; }
       public int? Age { get; set; }
       public PositionPlayer Position { get; set; }
   }

   [Tag("players")]
   [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Description("Update an existing Player")]
   [LocodeCss(Field = "col-span-12 sm:col-span-6", Fieldset = "grid grid-cols-8 gap-2", Form = "border overflow-hidden max-w-screen-lg")]
   [ExplorerCss(Field = "col-span-12 sm:col-span-6", Fieldset = "grid grid-cols-6 gap-8", Form = "border border-indigo-500 overflow-hidden max-w-screen-lg")]
   [Route("/players/{Id}", "PATCH")]
   [ValidateHasRole(Roles.Employee)]
   [AutoApply(Behavior.AuditModify)]
   public class UpdatePlayer : IPatchDb<Player>, IReturn<IdResponse>
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
   }

The modal opens correctly for new Player records. The URL changes correctly to ?edit=6 when editing, indicating the correct ID is being passed. The modal appears to function as expected with other DTOs, such as Booking, where both create and edit functionalities work. Question:
What might be causing the standard modal not to open for editing existing records? Is there a specific configuration or step I might be missing in ServiceStack or Blazor?


The modal appears to function as expected with other DTOs, such as Booking, where both create and edit functionalities work.

You've identified the correct behavior, the Create and Edit Forms only appears when the Data model has Create and/or Update APIs.
